# Synchronous and asynchronous call in Java and spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, call, synchronous

I need to update 3 data regions by making a synchronous call to one data region and asynchronous call to other 2 data regions using Java n spring.which is the best way to implement this?

Comment: What api do you have to call? (Rest, amqp,...)

Comment: I need to call Dao classes based upon the region code.

Comment: Interesting. You will need to create different datasource for sync connection and asyn connection. What do you mean by region code ?

Comment: Region code means regions. For example A, B and C. I Need to make synchronous call to region A by calling DAOA CLASS for performing crud operations and asynchronous call to region B and C by calling their corresponding classes as DAOB and DAOC for performing the same crud operstions .But I don't know how to write code for it. Will I have to use thread concept or async all annotation or what?

Comment: Please add more details to the question.  Such as how you will make the calls. It will help to show a code sample. As you are new I understand this may be your first question. Some details about whether you will call rest apis or soap or something else.

Comment: See I have to create a rest api in which at the same time 3 regions A, B and C Datacenters should get updated means all the 3 regions should have same updated data. I m not calling any API. I Need to call regions respective DAO classes for performing the operations. But I want to know how I can do it by using synchronous and asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the term region I understood you want to make a few http requests. One of them (the first) has to be blocking.

I would suggest you to have a look into spring's WebClient which let you make multiple requests in parallel.

The first (blocking) one can be achieved by a blocking Mono.

Here you can find a tutorial on Simultaneous Spring WebClient Calls:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-simultaneous-calls

Cheers